# For a picture preview I need to put 2 div elements vertically in front of a picture

Tags: css

For a picture preview I want to put 2 invisble divs (red/blue in the picture) in front of a picture for next/previous image functionality.
I would like to have the div ("pictureContainer"/ green bordered zone) to automatically take over the dimension of the containing picture but I can't find a PURE CSS solution without setting the width and the height manually.

[image: preview]

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.pictureContainer {
   /* I don't want to set width and hight manuyally. 
   The container should have the size if the contained image. */
    height: 50%;
    width:300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.leftSide {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 80%;
}

.rightSide {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 80%;
}
.picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pictureContainer">
    <div class="leftSide"></div>
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.9skips.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/anger-300x300.jpg">
    <div class="rightSide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also the container should be horizontally aligned.
Note: The full screen white div with the black border is used to close the picture preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change so the divs have `absolut: position`, let the image have it's natural size, container should be `display: inline-block;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.pictureContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.picture {
  display: block;
}

.leftSide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rightSide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pictureContainer">
    <div class="leftSide"></div>
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.9skips.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/anger-300x300.jpg">
    <div class="rightSide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The picture isn't aligned in the center anymore

Comment: try something display flex or text-align: center at container class to center the image

Comment: @tot Sorry about that, I missed it. Fixed in the example. I use flex for alignment.